# how to drag and drop Annotation marker in ios using mapbox sdk 3.0.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

Me new to use mapbox don't know which  delegate method to use for dragging and dropping the annontation marker, which i able to do till now is can  custom pin marker but like to drag and drop the pin and get respective location details through latitude and longitude.

Thank in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYv40.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zreAY.png

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How you tried anything until know? Can you show us your code or any errors??

Comment: This is pretty easy in the current version of the MapBox SDK: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/draggable-views/

Answer (score 0):

As of Mapbox iOS SDK v3.1.0, it is not easily possible to animate the movement of annotations.

Comment: is it possible to add annotation dynamically by following the finger